# Parallelising a basic java task

Tags: java, multithreading

I've created a simple sequential java program that calculates the inverse square root of a number using two different methods (math.pow() and Fast Inverse Square Root) to compare the accuracy of the results and the completion time. Now I need to parallelise this task, such that one thread calculates the inverse square root using math.pow and another thread calculates it using FISR. I am unsure how to go about this, since every multi-threaded example i've looked at has both threads working on two halves of a single problem, rather than just running seperate tasks. My source code is below:

```
package paralleltask;


public class ParallelTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the value:");
            Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userIn = userInputScanner.nextInt();
            long totalStart = System.nanoTime();
            long powStart = System.nanoTime();
            double testNum = Math.pow(userIn, -1.0/2);
            long powEnd = System.nanoTime();
            long powDuration = powEnd - powStart;
            long FISRStart = System.nanoTime();
            float xhalf = 0.5f*userIn;
            int i = Float.floatToIntBits(userIn);
            i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
            Float x = Float.intBitsToFloat(i);
            x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
            long FISREnd = System.nanoTime();
            long totalEnd = System.nanoTime();
            long totalDuration = totalEnd - totalStart;
            long FISRDuration = FISREnd - FISRStart;
            String testNumString = String.valueOf(testNum);
            String FISR = String.valueOf(x);
            System.out.println("The inverse square root using the math.pow() function is:");
            System.out.println(testNumString);
            System.out.println("It took " + powDuration + " milliseconds to complete");
            System.out.println("The inverse square root using the FISR function is:");
            System.out.println(FISR);
            System.out.println("It took " + FISRDuration + " milliseconds to complete");
            if (testNum > x) {
                System.out.println("The FISR approximation was " + (testNum - x) + " smaller than the math.pow() value.");
            }
            if (testNum < x) {
                System.out.println("The FISR approximation was " + (x - testNum) + " larger than the math.pow() value.");
            }
            System.out.println("The FISR function completed " + (powDuration - FISRDuration) + " milliseconds faster than math.pow");
            System.out.println("The total completion time was " + totalDuration + " milliseconds.");
        }
```

}

Comment: You should use a microbenchmark framework for starters

Comment: Spaghetti-code can't be parallelized.

Comment: First see benchmarking conecpts, then look at what @fge suggested. Also running it as two separate threads might not be a good idea.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why running it in parallel?

Comment: @isnot2bad I want to make the overall completion time of the program faster, so I want to make it multi-threaded rather than running the two calculation methods in series. This is not something i'm doing for personal reasons, it's a task I need to complete to demonstrate parallelising of a task, so switching to benchmarking framework is not the point. I don't care how fast parallelisation changes the calculation time, I just want to see HOW the program can be parallelised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call it parallelising but rather running two concurrent tasks (as you don't make one calculation to be run in multiple threads to make it faster but to run two separate calculations done in separate threads). If you want to run both concurrently you can use `Executor`.

First I would refactor the code to have both calculations as a separate tasks:

```
public class MathPowCalculation implements Callable<Double> {
    private final int input;

    public MatPowCalculation(int input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        // your calculation and time measurement and logging
        return result;
    }
}
```

And similar one for the second algorithm.

Then you can start both calculations concurrently and receive the first available result with:

```
int input = ...;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Future<Double>> results = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new MathPowCalculation(input), new FISRCalculation(input)));

for (Future<Double> result : results) {
    Double value = result.get();
    // do something with result value
}

executor.shutdown();
```

You might also take a look at [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), it might make your code simpler.

However, as others mentioned in the comments, you won't get reliable results. There is a whole science in micro benchmarking (JVM JIT optimizations etc.) and if you want to get useful results you need to use a framework for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the input, it certainly is a push in the right direction, but I need both outputs and their completion times for comparison, simply knowing which completed first is insufficient.

Comment: @broski I updated my answer based on your comment. If you want not only to print the times inside the call methods but receive them in `Future` you need to return your own wrapper class with result value and time info instead of just `Double`.

Comment: @broski And you have to call `invokeAll` instead of `invokeAny` as you are interested in both results, not only the first that completes.